# SSIS casting error

Tags: ssis

Im getting a "An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast" when using a derived column to format some error information.  My Expression is a follows

```
(DT_STR,255,1252)("Insert Employee Error - EmployeeID:" + (DT_STR,255,1252)ID)
```

The ID column is an integer. Strangely enough i'm doing something similar in another package and this works fine.  any ideas?

Heres my meta data passed to the derived column
[image]

Comment: I don't see a column named [ID] in the above screen shot. Is there more than one transformation being performed in the failing task? If so, try splitting it out into multiple derived transformations to help isolate the failure. Another thought it to wire up the failed error flow to another transformation and drop your data viewer on there as that will illuminate the bad data.

Comment: @billinkc the ID column is the 4th one down after forenames.  There were other transformations but i removed them to test.  It still errors.  The thing is if i set the original ole db destination to fastload the derived column works as expected.  The only problem being that it pulls all the rows into the errors table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any VMs handy for 2005 if that's your environment but the derived column transformation played looser with data types than 2008 so my test scenario, 2008 R2, ought to be valid regardless.

I see nothing wrong with your expression there. I spun up a quick package to verify your expectation that it works and it works for me.

[image: Derived column editor, no red here]
Added a row with null value based on Siva's comment but does not appear to be the source of the OP's problem
[image: Dataflow with nulls]

A few things to check on the metadata preceding the derived column transformation

- Is the casing of the column ID really ID?
- Is the data type really 4 byte signed int? (DT_I4)
- Try wrapping the ID column with [ID] or remove the ID completely and re-drag it from the Columns list

Comment: ive noticed that the ole destination component's accesmode is set to openrowset.  If i set it to fastload the derived column im getting from the error output works fine.  any ideas as i need to use openrowset so i can get only the data that errors into the error table?

Comment: Does SSIS warn on anything being incompatible or length/types not matching? What does your metadata look like going into the OLEDB destination versus your table definition. What database are you loading into?

Comment: Im using sqlserver 2008.  Ive also scanned through the meta data and still nothing stands out.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the meta data? Is it a design-time issue or run-time? Are you certain it's the derived column transformation that's blowing?

Comment: When i run it the derived column component goes red and it stops executing.  Its a run - time error.  Ill post the meta data in my OP

Comment: How many rows are you running through this? Is it worthwhile to drop a data viewer on the preceding step to look at the unique values for ID?

Comment: ive added a screenshot of the metadata above.  I have a dataviewer on the path and the data looks ok to me.  All there and no nulls